# Echarts: set default options for all series

Tags: echarts

let's say I have 4 columns (series) of data I need to display as lines.

```
value,series1,series2,series3,series4
V1,0,10,4,12
V2,8,13,15,10
V3,5,10,5,12
V4,12,7,8,12
V5,10,10,2,12
```

[Echarts graph as lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTKIj.jpg)
Is there an option to set in one sentence all settings for all series ?

the manual way is, for example:

```
xAxis: {type:'category'},
series:[{type:'line'},{type:'line'},{type:'line'},{type:'line'}],
```

... and I'm loooking for a simple way to set:

*all series*: {type:'line'}

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve that is doing something like that:

```
var data = [
    [V1,0,10,4,12],
    [V2,8,13,15,10],
    [V3,5,10,5,12],
    [V4,12,7,8,12],
    [V5,10,10,2,12]
];

var defaultSeries = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    defaultSeries.push({ type: 'line' });
}

var option = {
    xAxis: {type:'category'},
    series: defaultSeries,
}

myChart.setOption(option);
```

Comment: Thanks. This also worked for my barchart data: var data = [
        ['Year', '2015', '2016', '2017','2018'],
        ['A', ,5.3, 3.7]...

 var mySeries = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length-1; i++) {
  mySeries.push({ type: 'bar' });
 }